# Как вывести название таблицы в WPF C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, база-данных, datagrid

Всем Доброго времени суток!

Помогите пожалуйста.
Есть локальная база данных, вывожу ее в DataGrid, Как мне узнать название таблицы которая находиться в DataGrid и вывести в Label?
У меня есть форма администратора в которой можно работать со всеми таблицами в базе данных с помощью sql запросов и для того чтобы обновить данные в базе данных нужно знать в какой именно таблице обновлять.
Проект пишется на WPF.
Заранее благодарю.
Код при открытии формы

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kino.mdf; Integrated Security=True; ");
            string table = "UserA";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter as SqlDataAdapter);
            adapter.InsertCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            adapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.DeleteCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            tabgrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Код для работы с базой данных с помощью SQL команд

```
private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kino.mdf; Integrated Security=True; ");
                string script = scripter.Text.ToString();
                mycon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter ms_data = new SqlDataAdapter(script, mycon);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                ms_data.Fill(table);
                tabgrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView; ;
                mycon.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection lost");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Покажите код, как вы загружаете данные в `DataGrid`.

Comment: [DataTable.TableName](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.tablename?view=netframework-4.8)